# Iterate through List using for loop in C++

Tags: c++11

H, 
I have a list *Booklist* and now I want to iterate it for each element and I am doing like this but its not correct so can anybody suggest how to do ?

```
 Book::Notes(string booklist)
{
for(int i = 0; i < booklist.Size(); i++)
        {
             string B1= booklist[i];

          }
```

Comment: if `string` here is `std::string`, then this is not a list of strings, but one string, which is a sequence of `char`s. also there is no `Size`, it is spelled `size`. Do you mean to use `std::vector<std::string>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (auto &B : booklist) 
{
    // Do things with B
    std::cout << B << std::endl; 
}
```